# Predict function in survreg in r

Tags: r

I have this model in survival analysis:

```
full_model_lognormal <- survreg(Surv(DF$TimeDeath, DF$event) ~ age + sex + mutation +BM1 + BM2, data = DF,
                             dist = "lognormal")
```

I need to calculate the expected failure time of a male patient who is 51 years old, no gene mutation, and for BM1 he had the value 3.7 mg/dL and for BM2 the value 251 mg/dL.

I need to do it using the predict function, any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question is really a duplicate: [Finding the mean of the log-normal distribution in survival analysis in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18813751/finding-the-mean-of-the-log-normal-distribution-in-survival-analysis-in-r/18814414#18814414)

but cannot mark it as such because the answer (mine) has no upvotes or checkmark:

```
lfit <- survreg(Surv(time, status) ~ ph.ecog, data=lung)
pct <- 1:98/100   # The 100th percentile of predicted survival is at +infinity
ptime <- predict(lfit, newdata=data.frame(ph.ecog=2), type='quantile',
                 p=pct, se=TRUE)
matplot(cbind(ptime$fit, ptime$fit + 2*ptime$se.fit,
                          ptime$fit - 2*ptime$se.fit)/30.5, 1-pct,
         xlab="Months", ylab="Survival", type='l', lty=c(1,2,2), col=1)
 # The plot should be examined since you asked for a median survival time
 abline(h= 0.5)
 # You can  drop a vertical from the intersection to get that graphically 
.... or ...
 str(ptime)
List of 2
 $ fit   : num [1:98] 9.77 16.35 22.13 27.46 32.49 ...
 $ se.fit: num [1:98] 2.39 3.53 4.42 5.16 5.82 ...
```

You can extract the 50th percentile (which is the median survival) from that sequence of survival times with:

```
ptime$fit[which((1-pct)==0.5)]
# [1] 221.6023
```

If you wanted to get mean time you would not want to use a "100th quantile" since it is Infinity. You could, I suppose, calculate the mean of the 0.1-0.99 quantiles and divide by 0.99.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback, it's not really a duplicate because i am not asking to fund the median survival time, but the survival time for those specific parameters.

Comment: You didn't supply a data object that would allow a useful illustration, but if you had I would have shown you how to use the `newdata=...` argument to do what you requested.

Answer (score 1):

For predicting the response you can do something like the following:

```
require(survival)
fit <- survreg(Surv(time,status) ~ age + I(age^2), data=stanford2, 
               dist='lognormal') 
pred <- predict(fit, newdata=list(age=1:65), type='quantile', 
                p=c(.1, .5, .9))
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i know in theory how to use the predict model, but not how to fit exactly my question